# obtener captcha con curl

Tags: php, curl

encontre este codigo en internet, y quiero obtener su captcha de esta pagina http://www.ruat.gob.bo/vehiculos/consultageneral/InicioBusquedaVehiculo.jsf

su captcha se genera cada ves que refresco la pagina, es posible obtenerlo?

```
    <?php

    $cookie="cookie.txt";

    function open($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2) Gecko/20070219 Firefox/2.0.0.2');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);  
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }

    function between($string, $start, $end)
    {
        $out = explode($start, $string);

        if(isset($out[1]))
        {
            $string = explode($end, $out[1]);
            echo $string[0];
            return $string[0];
        }

        return '';
    }

    function get_captcha()
    {
        $url    = 'https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login.asp';
        $open   = open($url);
        $code   = between($open, '<img src='https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/captcha.asp', '">');
        return 'https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/captcha.asp' . $code;

    }

    function rahul()
    {
        $capth=htmlspecialchars($_POST['code']);

        echo $capth;

        $username="xyz"; 
        $password="abc"; 
        $url=url of the form in which you want to submit your data; 
        $cookie="cookie.txt";
        $veri=$capth;

        $com="Login";

        $postdata = "regno=".$username."&passwd=".$password."&vrfcd=".$veri."&submit=".$com;

        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);  // <-- add this line
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
        $result = curl_exec ($ch); 

        echo $result;  

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
    }
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <img src="<?php echo get_captcha(); ?>" border="0" /><br />
            <input type="text" name="code" value="<?= isset($_POST['code']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['code']) : '' ?>" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                rahul();
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Puedo preguntar para qué quieres realizar esto? Porque me parece que ReCaptcha está diseñado precisamente para evitar cosas como la que estás intentando hacer.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro hice un proyecto web y necesita hacer las consultas desde mi proyecto, es decir una especie de pagina camuflada

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro es posible obtener el captcha???

Comment: se puede obtener el captcha??

Comment: ¿Qué has hecho para modificar el script de arriba?¿comprendes lo que hace?

Answer (score 2):

Se supone que el captcha es precisamente para que no hagamos lo que deseas, al parcer esta complicado ya que son imagenes y no archivos planos, y estuve mirando y su formulario y viaja codificado estara dura tu tarea.

Comment: En cuyo caso sería bueno intentar obtener la URL de la imagen.

Comment: @ArtEze la imagen cambia cada vez que se recarga (incluso teniendo la misma URL)

Comment: se puede modificar esa pagina para que se pueda ver diferente solo la vista?

Answer (score 2):

Respuesta corta: No.

---

Respuesta larga: Puede, aunque seguramente no.

Intentar saltarse la comprobación del ReCAPTCHA no es tan trivial como pudiera parecer; no es simplemente una imagen que escribes el texto y se acabó, hay más cosas que entran en juego: cookies, comprobación de dominios, comprobación de rutas...

Como estás leyendo la página con `curl` (suponiendo que lo que quieres es recrear el formulario en tu página), podrías mostrarle la imagen del CAPTCHA al usuario y que él/ella la escriba, pero aún así podría fallar porque la misma URL cambia de imagen cada vez que se carga (y el ReCAPTCHA puede considerarlo como dos peticiones diferentes).

Incluso si lees la página y la presentas al usuario con la imagen correcta y el usuario la responde correctamente, puede que no funcione. Porque ReCAPTCHA comprueba que exista una cookie en el ordenador del cliente (algo que parece que el script que compartes intenta simular, aunque no estoy seguro de cómo funciona).

Y si todo lo anterior funciona, ReCAPTCHA sigue comprobando que el dominio del servidor que hizo la petición del CAPTCHA coincide con el que realiza el envío. Y luego habrá otras comprobaciones que desconozco.

---

Como te ponía en mi comentario, ReCAPTCHA está diseñado precisamente para evitar cosas como lo que estás intentando hacer (envío automático de formularios o *impersonar* el formulario real en tu sitio para reenviar la información).

Eso no quiere decir que sea imposible. Que los diseñadores de ReCAPTCHA sean expertos en ciberseguridad no quiere decir que los hackers no lo sean. Y de hecho, consiguieron descifrar las versiones antiguas y saltarse la validación en algunos casos.

Buscando en Internet hay sitios en los que se habla de herramientas que ayudan con la comprobación (aunque generalmente hablan de versiones antiguas), o como sólo hace falta entrar un valor correcto y ya funciona para todos (con el nuevo ReCAPTCHA)... pero no sé cómo de fiables (o confiables) son los métodos que exponen.

Y la verdad, eso ya sería entrar en temas mucho más complejos (y con posibles ramificaciones legales) de los que una pregunta en StackOverflow permite.